# Is it possible to compress valence electrons within a copper wire using two electric fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, experimental-physics

I am wondering if the free electrons within a straight copper wire could be compressed towards the center of the wire with the use of two electric fields created by two sets of parallel plates.

I believe that the free electrons within the wire can be compressed to a certain extent before the Coulomb force between the free electrons stops any further compression, but I am not really sure whether any compression will occur. I have searched for an answer to this question on the Internet, but so far have not found one yet.

Please reference the drawing below:

[image]

This drawing is showing a cross-sectional view of a rubber-insulated straight electrical wire with one end of the wire located between a set of parallel plates and the other end located between another set of parallel plates. The copper wire is positioned in the middle of the two sets of plates going through holes that exist in each of the two positively charged plates. (How exactly this whole apparatus would be put together mechanically is of secondary concern to me.)

When the two electric fields are generated, the free electrons in the sections of the copper wire located between each of the two sets of plates should be pushed by the two electric fields inwards towards the center of the wire, compressing all the free electrons within the wire. When the electric fields are turned off, the free electrons should flow back to the two ends of the wire.

Is it possible to compress free electrons within a copper wire using two electric fields?

**EDIT**

After considering the comments about the original design of this electric field apparatus, I have redesigned it and believe that this new apparatus should accomplish the goal of compressing valence electrons within a straight copper wire.

[image]

Comment: I believe to some extent it should be possible bur for what purpose(s)?

Comment: @Gert, it is mostly to help my understanding of the relationship between electric fields and charged particles. On the flip side, if free electrons can be compressed in a wire, then electrons should be able to be pulled out of a wire by reversing the polarity on the two sets of parallel plates.

Comment: I don't understand why the positive plate is the one facing the copper. It seems to me valence electrons will rather get attracted to the ends. If I were to move electrons to the center of the cable I would use negative ions on the ends.

Comment: @Exocytosis yes, the polarity isn't correct, assuming he wants the compression to take place midway the copper wire...

Comment: @Exocytosis, that's an interesting observation. I believe that the free/valence electrons in the sections of the wire the lie between the two sets of plates will be pushed out of those sections by the electric fields and will they then having a pushing contest with the valence electrons being pulled in by the positively charged plates. These pushing contests should result in a high compression of electrons within those very small areas of the wire.

Comment: @Gert, it doesn't really have to happen at the midway point, I really just want to know if there will be any inward movement of valence electrons, or if the overall Colcumb force of the all the electrons together would just be too strong for any movement at all.

Comment: I don't think so. Electrons in the negative plate will be attracted toward the positive plate (but stay on the negative plate unless a high voltage breaks it), only because there is a deficiency of electrons there. If there are free electrons next to your positive plate, there will be no difference of potential.

Comment: The higher the *potential*, the higher the force acting on the electrons, pushing them together. Coulombic repulsion of course pushes in the opposite direction. But the higher the potential, the more 'compression' you'll have...

Comment: The way I see it, both sides of the conductor have to be at the same, **negative** potential.

Comment: Given the wire capacitance, you can readily calculate how much charge you would need to move on to it to reach a given potential.